# Building meshes conforming to terrain deformation

Tags: unity, terrain, mesh

I have an uneven terrain on which the player is supposed to build buildings. For most structures I can just fudge the foundations, have them extend through the terrain.
For roads, pipes, tracks and such I do have however the problem how to make them line up. What techniques can I best use to make the meshes of adjacent pieces line up, making it conform to the terrain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with many other obstacles of procedural geometry, this problem can be solved with splines! It’s only one of many ways to address this engineering challenge.

Here is an [excellent tutorial on how to play with splines for this exact purpose](https://youtu.be/o9RK6O2kOKo). [Here’s another one demonstrating road placement](https://youtu.be/Osq69-SWcWY).

Unity doesn’t have a purely mathematical code-based spline implementation, so i [made one a while back for my own ease of use](https://github.com/nauticaldev/UnitySpline). I suggest an implementation like mine if you prefer to implement this with more code than editor, as it makes more sense to me for real-time applications.